# Unable to install Transcend Jetdrive 520 SSD on my Macbook Air 2013

Tags: macbook-pro

I am trying to erase my new SSD (Transcend Jetdrive 520 ) for Macbook Air using Disk Utility but it is failing & giving the error "Could not mount disk" after erase.
Same is happening in terminal mode as well.
I purchased the 480 GB model but Disk Utility and Teminal are showing only 1024 MB

My terminal experience is as follows:

```
Last login: Sun Aug 27 12:20:48 on ttys000
Visheshs-MacBook-Air:~ visheshgupta$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +120.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 8CB5951A-2E74-4F72-BF5E-436BA87DF490
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.1 GB     disk2
   1:                       0xEE                         1.1 GB     disk2s1

Visheshs-MacBook-Air:~ visheshgupta$ diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ Emptied /dev/disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk2s1 as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) with name Emptied
newfs_hfs: 
WriteBuffer:  pwrite(3, 0x10debf000, 1044480, 116338688): Input/output error
newfs_hfs: write (sector 227224): Invalid argument
Mounting disk
Could not mount disk2s1 after erase
Error: -69832: File system formatter failed
Visheshs-MacBook-Air:~ visheshgupta$
```

Comment: This doesn't seem fun... is the SMART data reading all good?

Comment: NO... it says NOT SUPPORTED (in disk utility). And sorry its Mac Book Air late 2012 model bought in Jan 2013. I am in India and in a part where i could not find any suport for my device, I will be highly obliged to you for all the help. and on erasing it through diskutility it erases but comes up with MBR format where as i chose GUID.

Comment: Right, forgot it was in an enclosure. You could take it out and put it in a different enclosure, but that'll take time and money.

Comment: It's quite possible the drive is bad. Have you considered RMAing it?

Comment: How to do RMA..? I tried puting the drive directly to macbook and boot the mac from original drive by connecting to the enclousre. It booted perfectly but diskutility failed again.

Comment: Just spoke to my vendor and he has asked to ship it back for inspection and i might be getting a newer 1 soon.